# Continuous cycling through all objects in a table using django

Tags: python, django, django-views, orm

As a learner of the django framework, I face the challenge of looping through all primary keys of a table, beginning with the first, and at the end of the sequence, to start all over again. The `id` field is  an auto-incrementing serial field in postgres.  A very basic breakdown of the concept is as follows:

*models.py*

```
...
class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

*views.py*

```
def home(request, id=None):
    from .models import Event

    first_obj = Event.objects.order_by('id').first()
    my_json = serialize('json', first_obj, fields=('event_name', 'timestamp'))

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'items': my_json})

def get_next(request):

     #set viewed=True on current object
    .save()
     return redirect('home') #move to next object
```

*home.html*

```
...
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'get_next' %}">
<button>confirm</button>
</form>
...
```

The idea is to send the `my_json` object to an html template.  A user clicks a button, which should then mark the current object as viewed (sets `viewed` from False to True), then the next object should be fetched (by incremental primary key), and so on.  If it has reached the last object, the first object (pk=1) should be fetched next, and the cycle continues. I would like to avoid making ajax requests and think a second url would be the most effective way of doing this, but am not sure how to proceed.

Should the current pk id be sent back and forth between requests and incremented each time?  Is there a built-in method for this concept in django? What would be an efficient method of cycling through all primary keys? Any advice here on how to best structure this concept would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you post to get_next url, you should send the PK of the current event. Then `event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=request.post.get("pk")` will give you the current event. `event.viewed = True` `event.save()`.

In your home view, you should do:

```py
event = Event.objects.filter(viewed=False).order_by("pk")
if not event.exists():
    Event.objects.all().update(viewed=False) #only in Django 2.2+ I think
    event = Event.objects.order_by("pk").first()
else:
    event = event.first()
return ...
```

I think this will give you a cycle when all are viewed we set them back to not viewed and start with the first one again.

Also, if you are using integer PK's, and if you haven't defined otherwise in the Meta of your class, order_by is not necessary. By default they are ordered by PK.